# Upgrade all nuget packages from .net 4.0 to .net 4.5

Tags: .net, nuget

I am uprgading my solution from .NET 4.0 to .NET 4.5. Upgrading solution is easy (just changing target framework in every project), but I have a lot of nuget refereces. All of them are to .NET 4.0 libs. How can I upgrade them to .NET4.5 automatically?

Comment: Why do you think you have to?  They'll work just fine on 4.5

Comment: @HansPassant If I'm not mistaken the package will be compiled for 4.0, which means it won't be able to take advantage of the changes in 4.5. For example Entity Framework where many improvements to EF5.0 "reside within the core components that ship with .NET 4.5".